# Count by specific values in different columns

Tags: sql, function, group-by

```
Register ID    Status        Process 
102            chat          end state
102            chat          end state
102            relo          end state
103            bifurcate     end state
103            diverge       transfer state
104            chat          null state
104            transfer      null state
104            relo          retro state
105            transfer      null state
105            emancipate    retro state
105            chat          hello state
105            chat          inner state
106            rater         end state
106            chat          null state
107            rater         null state
107            relo          transfer state
107            chat          intro state
```

What I am  trying to get at is whenever I have the value "chat" in status column only once by sender ID and also the count of value "end state" is zero in the process column for the same Sender ID i want to count that sender id and display those sender ID's ..Output that I am expecting below: Can someone please help!

Output
Count of distinct register ID that have only one chat status and no end state process   2

Distinct register ID that have only one chat status and no end state process 
104
106

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select RegisterID 
from your_table
group by RegisterID
having 
sum(case when Status='chat' then 1 end) = 1
and
sum(case when Process = 'end state' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Or if you need count of such `RegisterID`s insetad of list, then:

```
select count(*) from (
    select RegisterID 
    from your_table
    group by RegisterID
    having 
    sum(case when Status='chat' then 1 end) = 1
    and
    sum(case when Process = 'end state' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
) t
```